# Build SQL Query with Customized Virtual Values

Tags: sql

If I'll execute below query then I'm getting more than 1000 records here

```
select 
   ID, name, 'Default value' as "Other" 
from 
   emp_table
```

Output:

```
ID  |   Name    |   Other
---------------------------------
1   |   H       |   Default value
2   |   V       |   Default value
3   |   D       |   Default value
```

but here I have added on a virtual column with default value of `Default Value`. The default value should reflect only for first row instead with all the rows

Expected output:

```
ID  |   Name    |   Other
----------------------------------
1   |   H       |   Default value
2   |   V       |   null
3   |   D       |   null
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server you can use ROW_NUMBER() to add a row number to the query and then use a `CASE` statement to write the default value or null:

```
select 
    ID, 
    NAME, 
    CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by NAME) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Default Value' 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS [Other] 
from emp_table
ORDER BY NAME
```

The ordering in `OVER` should match the ordering of the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,
       name,
       CASE
           WHEN ID=1 THEN 'Default value'
           ELSE NULL
       END AS "Other"
FROM emp_table
```

Comment: above values are sample.ID and other columns values will be in randomly will get it.So can't specify with particular ID for default value

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   e1.ID, e1.name, 
   case when e1.id = e2.min_id then 'Default value' else NULL end as "Other" 
from 
   emp_table e1, (select min(id) min_id from emp_table) e2
```